# reversibility scalar conservation law

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I am reading here and there (see for instance Denis Serre systems of conservation laws 1- p.36), the following for which I can't spot the mistake I am making that prevents me from arriving to the same conclusion:

A weak solution to a scalar conservation law is $u \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}\times[0;s])$ such that:

$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}\times[0;s]}u(x,t)\phi_t(x,t) + f(u(x,t))\phi_x(x,t) dxdt + \int_{\mathbb{R}}u_0(x)\phi(0,x)dx =0,\\ \forall \phi \in D(\mathbb{R}\times[0;s]).$$

It is then infered that if $u$ is a weak solution, then $v(x,t):= u(-x,s-t)$ is a weak solution with initial datum $v_0(x)=u(-x,s)$ beyond the fact that one should give a meaning to $u(-x,s)$ a change of variable in the weak formulation does not give to me what I should get, making it I obtain:

$$\begin{aligned}&\iint_{\mathbb{R}\times[0;s]}v(x,t)\phi_t(x,t) + f(v(x,t))\phi_x(x,t) dxdt + \int_{\mathbb{R}}v_0(x)\phi(0,x)dx \\
&\quad =  \iint_{\mathbb{R}\times[0;s]}u(x,t)\phi_t(-x,s-t) + f(u(x,t))\phi_x(-x,s-t) dxdt\\
&\phantom{\quad =} + \int_{\mathbb{R}}u(x,0)\phi(-x,s)dx\\
&\quad = 2\int_{\mathbb{R}}u(x,0)\phi(-x,s)dx\\
&\quad \neq 0\\
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are right, to be able to exhaust $u(\cdot,s)$ as an $L^{1}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R})$ function you would need more than just $u\in L^{1}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}\times(0,s))$ but continuity, i.e.
$u\in C([0,s];L^{1}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}))$. Most authors are not very careful about a sound and rigorous presentation, that is why I started [Different kind of Weak Solutions...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851509/conservation-laws-difference-and-reasonability-weak-solutions-integral-solutio).

To your second question, I think you forgot the - sign when you substitute for $v(x,t)$ the function $u(-x,s-t)$ and perform an integration by substitution (the differential gives the minus when substituting)...then you get quite the opposite sign and this is cancelling out the initial or end condition.